# Web Design w/CMS

Tags: drupal, joomla, content-management-system, adobe

I recently "inherited" an IT company that has a creative wing that does websites.  Business is very good, but it seems like our throughput is very low.  It's taking 3-6 months per site for just basic sites (no ecommerce, etc).  From what I can tell, the process goes like this:

- designers design the site using Adobe products
- once those mock-ups look good, we outsource the files to be "sliced"
- once we get the artifacts back from the "slicers", the web coders plug the information into a Joomla site
- the site goes live

My question:  is this the correct approach?  I don't know enough about CMSs to know if we're using them in the way they're intended to be used.  If there is a better process that you know of, or a better CMS that is easier to plug the results of the slicing into, I would love to hear about it.

Thanks for any feedback you might provide.

Answer (score 1):

Ughh. I hate the process you describe. Designers who don't understand much HTML do the design, and then this "slicing" process involves cramming stuff that was never designed to be HTML into HTML.

Unfortunately, at my agency, we've found it difficult to find folks who design from the get-go in HTML/CSS.

But to your question about time, consider this. I'm a sole web developer working for an agency. We spent 4 months rebuilding our own site (a pretty simple site). But 3 of those months were spent going back and forth with the designer making changes.

I didn't start work on the site until one month before launch. From that point all I had was Photoshop files. I recreated the look of those files in Drupal templates and did all the other development (including some medium-complexity javascript) in just one month.

During that month, the design of 40% of the site changed dramatically. If it weren't for that, I would have been done in two weeks.

And I'm just one guy. And I don't consider myself a fast coder AT ALL. Your folks are taking WAY too long.

Answer (score 0):

The web programmers should be able to slice the files, at the end of the day, they are the ones programming it so they should know what they want/need more than anyone else, it will save money and time theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, 3-6 months for the workflow you described sounds painful. That's a timeline better suited to a site that includes a high level of custom data handling functionality. However, beyond the considerable mismatch between the process you describe and the time it's taking, the scope of this question seems pretty wide for stackoverflow.

I'd start by editing your question to indicate the amount of time typically spent on each of these steps. Just based on what you list I can't possibly imagine that taking 3 months, let alone 6.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if "Business is very good" and you're spending "3-6 months per site" then the only conclusion is that these are very high design websites with good margins. So you don't sound like you're in the slice and dice $14.95 a month website business.

Given that the sites we build often have a primary stake holder who is subject to corporate design guidelines and marketing criteria followed by product positioning criteria it's not unusual for us to spend 3 months getting the design work done. We can go through 3 design iterations (all of which the clients pay for).

The only difference to your situation is that our designers are 'web designer' and either understand how to build a Photoshop file to be 'sliced' or work in conjunction with the people that will be doing the slicing.

So, the only thing I find odd is that you send out the work to be sliced.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the process but the resource arrangement seems not correct. If it's a design company, I would expect you should have your own designers who can slice those images, rather than outsourcing. This will improve your efficiency and speed.

As for the CMS, Joomla is a much complicated CMS which is suitable for larger websites that require extensive CMS features. For normal corporate websites, I would suggest to use WordPress. It's very lightweight, easy to use, easy to skin and easy to setup.